# Ensure that all data is transferred in the Multipeer Framework for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, multipeer-connectivity

So I am using the Mutltipeer Framework for iOS in a game where you shoot dots from one screen to another. To get the dot from one device to the other, I send data via Multipeer and accept data via NSNotification. Sometimes, some data does not get sent. How can I ensure that every piece of information is sent??

Comment: Have you made sure that you are flushing the data?

Comment: When you send the data, are you using the transmission mode 'Reliable'?

Comment: @Gliderman what do you mean by flushing the data??

Comment: And, yes, @Keith Coughtrey I am using the reliable transmission mode"

Comment: @PoKoBros When communications are sending data, either to a file or out of the device, there is typically a buffer that holds your data until it fills up (and then it writes).  I'm not sure what the method is for this, but some sort of `flush()` command will push out all the data in the output buffer to where it is supposed to go.  Again, just a thought, but something I've run into before.